# Highcharts - Pie/Donut Chart group small portion

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart, donut-chart

A Pie/Donut chart will be easier to read if small portions could be grouped together to others. I would like to add this feature to [zeppelin-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts)

In this example [Donut Chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut). There are small portions for Safari which are impossible to read. Its better to group it together to "Safari Other Versions"

```
{
    name: 'Safari versions',
    categories: ['Safari v5.0', 'Safari v5.1', 'Safari v6.1', 
                 'Safari v6.2', 'Safari v7.0', 'Safari v7.1', 'Safari v8.0'],
    data: [0.3, 0.42, 0.29, 0.17, 0.26, 0.77, 2.56],
}
```

I'd like to group the small portions to others like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockiey/gu5xzfq7/)

```
{
    name: 'Safari versions',
    categories: ['Safari Other Versions', 'Safari v8.0'],
    data: [2.21, 2.56],
}
```

I go through Highcharts API doc, but I have not found any configuration which could enable this.

How can I implement this feature in Highcharts?

Comment: Have you considered using a pie chart with drilldown? This should be easily converted to a donut chart, if you so chose. See http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown.

Comment: @MikeZavarello, thanks for comments. Since I'm provide to a tool, it is other users to choose what chart to use. And for a single pie chart, how to group small portions together to others, so that there are only few (like 5) pieces in a pie chart.

Comment: How are your data coming into the chart? I'm thinking that perhaps you could run a function where pie slices less than a certain percent could be grouped together first, and then added to the chart as your series data.

Comment: I am trying to convert from Spark DataFrame -> Highcharts. Please check https://github.com/knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts

Comment: I think that Mikes idea for add a filter function before making our chart is good idea. You can also make this function on load callback function. Look at this example, maybe it will help you with your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/b33ynvaq/1/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Thanks very much for the solution. It can solve my issue. Are you considering put into as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can add filter function before making your chart. You can also filter your data on load event callback function.

Here you can find simple example of code filtering data in callback function:

```
var groupSmallData = function(series, number) {
    var groupValue = 0,
        newData = [];
    Highcharts.each(series.data, function(p) {
        if (p.y < number) {
          groupValue += p.y;
        } else {
          newData.push([p.name, p.y])
        }
    });
    newData.push(['others', groupValue]);
    series.setData(newData)
}
```

Here you can find live example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/b33ynvaq/1/